# Exclude pages from Mediawiki recent changes

Tags: mediawiki

Does anyone know how to exclude pages from the Recent Changes page in mediawiki?  I have a testing page where users can play with syntax and formatting etc. but don't want every little change to show up on the recent changes page.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`SpecialRecentChangesQuery`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SpecialRecentChangesQuery) hook to exclude the specific page by title, like this:

```
$wgHooks['SpecialRecentChangesQuery'][] = 'rcExcludeSandbox';

function rcExcludeSandbox( $conds ) {
    $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
    $conds[] = 'rc_title != ' . $dbr->addQuotes( 'Sandbox' );
    return true;
}
```

This will prevent all changes on the page "Sandbox" from appearing in Special:RecentChanges.

Comment: I added this code to the LocalSettings.php and it works! Thanks.  I'm no sure this is the best place? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind writing some PHP, consider using the http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/OldChangesListRecentChangesLine hook. If you set $s to an empty string for a given page, then those edits shouldn't appear in Special:RecentChanges.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to put your page in a different namespace, and not search it by default. Unfortunately that functionality isn't in the current version of Mediawiki.

I think you have to use [Namespace Manager](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Namespace_manager), It doesn't look like it is finished, but you could give it a shot. It seems like the plan is to add it to a future version.

You could just make a page named [Sandbox](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Sandbox), and then allow users to edit that page. If you use [Enhanced Recent Changes](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aEnhanced_recent_changes) all those edits will appear together, so it won't bother you too much.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using mw 1.15.1, and don't have much option to change versions at the moment. I do use the enhanced functionality and also have a shot list of recently changed pages on the main page. If users are messing about with my testing page, then the edits show up here too.  I'd like them not to.

Comment: Yea it would be a lot of work to integrate this into an existing installation of Mediawiki.

Comment: On mediawiki.org for example the sandbox is included in the recent changes, so maybe its something that you will have to just deal with, if what Joshua Lerner suggested doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a separate wiki instance. It is not that hard to set up and then you can also test functional changes in isolation as well.